# Excel VBA stop code where conditions are met

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, stoppropagation

I'm struggling getting my code to work.

I have a button on the excel sheet that when triggers

1. checks required fields value is 0, if not then message box and end code
2. checks if the reference number already exists on a master tab, if the reference exisits, message box and end code
3. if 1 and 2 pass then perform a copy and paste as values for 3 ranges then message box.

I've tried a number of options but can't get it to work

```
    Function Mand() As Boolean
   'checks that mandatory fields have been updated

   If Sheets("INPUT").Range("C11") > 0 Then MsgBox "Mandatory Fields Missing" & vbNewLine & "Changes Not Saved!"
   Mand = True

    End Function


    Function RecEx() As Boolean
    'checks that the reference number does not exisit on the High Level master list

    dup = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Sheets("High_Level_List").Columns(1), Sheets("INPUT").Range("C17"))
    If dup > 0 Then MsgBox "This Record Exists!!!" & vbNewLine & "If saving an update, use the Save Changes button"
    RecEx = True   

    End Function


    Sub RegisterNewRec()
    ' checks 2 functions, if either are TRUE then exit, otherwise update master

    If Mand Then Exit Sub

        If RecEx Then Exit Sub

    End If

    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Sheets("INPUT").Range("AO2:CX2")
    Sheets("High_Level_List").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(rng.Rows.Count, rng.Columns.Count).Cells.Value = rng.Cells.Value

    'more code that updates master

    MsgBox "Record added to Master"

    End Sub
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/using-ifthenelse-statements

Comment: https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/or_vba.php

Comment: Your if statement is weird. It should just be (separately) `If Mand Then Exit Sub` `If RecEx Then Exit Sub` There should be no `End If`

Comment: You could also do `If Mand Or RecEx Then Exit Sub` in a single line. Again, no need for the `End If`

Comment: You should also be getting an error saying `End If without block if` which would be a useful error to include in your original post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said in my comment, the `End If` doesn't need to be there:

```
If Mand Then Exit Sub
If RecEx Then Exit Sub
```

^ How the code should look

Alternatively you could use:

```
If Mand Or RecEx Then Exit Sub
```

You also need to make sure that you only set your function to `True` if the above is true by including the `End If` block:

```
Function Mand() As Boolean
If Sheets("INPUT").Range("C11") > 0 Then 
   MsgBox "Mandatory Fields Missing" & vbNewLine & "Changes Not Saved!"
   Mand = True
End If
End Function

Function RecEx() As Boolean
dup = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Sheets("High_Level_List").Columns(1), Sheets("INPUT").Range("C17"))
If dup > 0 Then 
    MsgBox "This Record Exists!!!" & vbNewLine & "If saving an update, use the Save Changes button"
    RecEx = True
End If
End Function
```

The problem is that you were setting the `RecEx` and the `Mand` to true either way.

Comment: Thanks, @user1274820 - It now works as I have added If Mand Or RecEx Then Exit Sub. However when neither of these are true (i.e. all mandatory fields are complete and the reference number does not exist, nothing happens. No messages and the rest of the code does not run (copy data to different tabs). Thanks.

Comment: Is it actually making it to the next line? You can put a `Debug.Print "Made it!"` after your if statement - if it makes it there, then something is giong wrong in the rest of your code (most of which is missing from your post)

Comment: Thanks, I added the debug and nothing happens (no made it!). Works when either functions are TRUE, just not when both are false. Sorry, quite new at this!

Comment: Ahh no problem man I see the issue here. You need to wrap your if statements in the functions with end ifs like so - see my edit in 30 seconds